# How to restrict mouse movement to a div with jquery library

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mousemove

I tried to restrict mouse movement to div area when the right button is pressed in this div,  with jquery library. How can I do this?Or  a best question I could do this? similar to restrict movement of a screen portion.

Comment: Repost. Try this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595909/how-to-completley-disable-any-mouse-click or this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350227/js-restrict-mouse-movement-with-axis-when-shift-pressed-for-draggable-element

Comment: @ClaudioLudovicoPanetta I think you have not understood the question. I do not want to completley disable any MOUSE CLICK. I Need mouse clic events but I need restrict movement only in a specific Div.Please re-think your punctuation

Comment: Martin - if WTK's answer is wrong, try adding more description to your question - perhaps you can add a diagram or jsFiddle - and show people what you are trying to do.

Comment: can you explain a little more that why you are doing this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is: you can't.

You can't control on which area user moves his mouse. It's his mouse afterall (joke). In all seriousness - it's probably security/usability/common sense feature. Imagine the Internet where web developers could control area on which user may move his cursor.